# Migrations don't create new database in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make a small sample app with ASP.NET Core and create a database to use for a calendar.
I added the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package and added some models for users and a custom database context, like this(pasted in 1 place):

```
   public class ReservationModel
    {
        [Column("Id")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Date")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ReserverId { get; set; }
    }

   public class UserModel
    {
        [Column("Id")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("IsAdmin")]
        [Required]
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    }

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReservationModel> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

And I am configuring it like this:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>
       (o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.
        GetConnectionString("MyNewDatabase")));

    }
```

Here are my connection strings:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyNewDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyNewDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "initial": "catalog=MyNewDb;",
    "integrated": "security=true"
  }
```

I run these commands in the console:

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration
Update-Database
```

Both finish successfully with no errors.

The problem is, I don't see my new created database anywhere in the Server Explorer. I tried using Microsoft SQL Management Studio as well, but all I can see are the 4 system databases. I don't see my new one being created.

I tried opening a new connection to .\SQLEXPRESS and I still only get the 4 system databases.

I've been looking at the documentation and watching online tutorials and I they do the exact steps as above, to make a simple database for the app, however it doesn't work for me.
I should also mention that I don't have any Database.EnsureCreated() left in the project, so that's not it either.
I also tried running the website and it starts up with no errors on initialization, tho it's just a bunch of simple texts right now.
I seem to be missing something. In the tutorials it always appears in the server explorer after doing the initial migrations and refreshing.

Comment: When you open SSMS on the login window is a server_name/instance.  In c# replace in the  connection string (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb with the server_name/instance from SSMS.  Also try closing SSMS and open SSMS after running c#.

Comment: The database is creating, you just need to see where, the connection string is key

Comment: Out of curiosity, I just replicated your code here. All seems good here, its created the database and tables. I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Comment: Try to insert some data, and you'll know for sure.

Comment: In Visual Studio, use "SQL Server Object Explorer" (not to be mixed with "Server Explorer") and look into "SQL Server\(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" nodes